# What are the .pro files in the VHDL OsvvmLibraries

Tags: vhdl

What are the .pro files in the VHDL OsvvmLibraries?

the obvious answer is that its a list of VHDL files the simulator needs to read...  But, I've never seen this particular build file format before.

What VHDL simulators support reading of .pro files?  Is this the input to a python script that calls a VHDL simualtor?  Or is it a file format that's built into a particular VHDL simulator.

Answer (score 2):

They are *.tcl files that use OSVVM's procedure application layer that abstracts away tool commands necessary to build a design.   This breaks down running a simulation into:

- library   `library_name`        Create and/or open a library
- analyze  `filename.vhd`         Compile a vhdl file (extension .vhdl also supported)
- simulate  `design-unit-name`    Run a simulation

Since many commands use the same options, we try to minimize specifying them by having analyze and simulate use the library referenced by the previous library command.  You can specify the VHDL version use SetVHDLVersion and analyze will use that revision - although most of OSVVM requires VHDL-2008.

The purpose of the abstraction layer is that (after sourcing the StartUp.tcl or alternate script) these commands work in Aldec ActiveHDL, Aldec RivieraPro, Mentor ModelSim, Mentor QuestaSim, GHDL, Synopsys VCS (with the October patch to VCS).  We are working with Cadence so the scripts work with Cadence Xcelium, however, not all of our regression tests are passing yet on Xcelium.  We are also working on scripts for Xilinx XSIM.

Rather than using tcl's source, we use OSVVM's build or include.   Build starts a log point; include continues with the log started by the current build.   Both reference files relative to the directory the script is in - rather than the directory that your simulator is running in, so you no longer have to pass that.

In the 2021.09 release, in addition to a log file, a build creates a test completion status results in a YAML database.   We expect in a future release to have additional capability to convert the YAML file to a JUnit test completion file to support better integration with continuous integration tools.

Further information is in the README file (that is rendered at the bottom of the github page):
https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM-Scripts

There is also pdf documentation (generated from the README.rst mentioned previously):
[https://github.com/OSVVM/Documentation/blob/main/Script_user_guide.pdf](https://github.com/OSVVM/Documentation/blob/master/Script_user_guide.pdf)

In Mentor and Aldec, you start the tools and then `source path-to-osvvm/OsvvmLibraries/Scripts/StartUp.tcl`.  Then you can compile all of OSVVM (utilities and VC) by doing `build path-to-osvvm/OsvvmLibraries` (it automatically finds OsvvmLibraries.pro).

I run GHDL using MSYS2 and then start tclsh using `winpty tclsh`.   Then I do the source above and do the builds.